# Unable to resolve IPs using dns for Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have just tried to run a windows container using Azure Container Instances, however it seems the container can't resolve DNS for the server i would like it to connect too.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Core.Services.DamAuthenticationService.Login(String username, String password) in C:\build\Core.Services\DamAuthenticationService.cs:line 89
   at Core.Services.DamAuthenticationService..ctor(DamInfo damInfo) in C:\build\Core.Services\DamAuthenticationService.cs:line 32
   at JobCruncher.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\build\JobCruncher\Startup.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at JobCruncher.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\build\JobCruncher\Program.cs:line 13
   at JobCruncher.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I know the DNS name resolves from Azure, I can access it from other VMs on Azure.

Any indications of what can be done to fix it?

Comment: What the DNS that you want the container to connect and what you have done about the image?

Comment: The image is a pretty standard dotnet core windows nanoserver image, and it works when running the image on Docker on Windows Server. The Hostname i want to connection to is `mm-dam.dev.digizuite.com`

Comment: does your container has a public IP or is it part of a VNET?

Comment: Neither. It doesn't receive requests itself, so it shouldn't need a public ip. And VNETs are not support for windows containers as far as I can see.

Comment: How do you ruin the image on Window Server?

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot ping google.com nor its IP.